# When is supervisor strategy called?

Tags: scala, akka

When is the supervisor strategy invoked ? Is it when the exception is thrown for an Actor. In below code :

```
@Override
public SupervisorStrategy supervisorStrategy() {

    System.out.println("supervisorStrategy");
   return strategy;
}
```

The println statement is not invoked when actor is created. Is this expected behaviour ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike the not-to-well-named `receive` method, which is only called during Actor initialization to acquire the `PartialFunction` that will handle incoming messages, the `supervisorStrategy` method is used when failures occur. It is a regular method that does the work of deciding how to handle a failure in a descendant Actor.

Hmm... I just noticed you're using Java, so the part about `receive` is presumably different for you, but the `supervisorStrategy` statement still applies.

Comment: "Unlike the not-to-well-named receive method, which is only called during Actor initialization" why not to well named ? The receive method is called whenever "tell" is called on the supervisor so not only at initialization ?

Comment: That's exactly why it's poorly named, at least in Scala. That is *not* when / how it's called. In Scala Akka, `receive` is called once to get the `PartialFunction` that is applied to each incoming method. A better name would have been `initialReceiver`.

Comment: im clearly not understanding something as I have multiple tell commands in a supervisor and it appears that receive is invoked an equal number times to the amount of tell calls.

Comment: Since Java doesn't have first-class functions as Scala does, I presume it works differently there. But even in Scala to distinguish a call to `receive` from one to the `PartialFunction` it returns, you'd have to put a log or println both inside the function body and outside it. The one outside would be called once. The one inside would be called once per message (naturally). That's why the name is so confusing.

Comment: it does seem to work differently in java. thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Good point Randall, it would be a nice thing to call out in the docs.